# Associations between 4 Models for a booking website

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a beginner in Rails, and I am currently having trouble making and imagining how associations would work on my current project, which is a sort of booking website for travels.
I currently have 4 models: User, Traveller, Trip and Cart.

**Users** are mainly for authentication (I used Devise). They can have many Travellers, just like you would on a booking website, you can book for many people on the same account.

The **Cart** is self-explanatory, basically as a User you have a single cart, and can add Trips to it, and then checkout and buy the trips.

A **Trip** can't have more than 8 Travellers, so for example 2 Users booked 4 Travellers each (4 would probably be the max you can have per User), and the Trip is full, and nobody can book it anymore.

You can only book a **Trip** once per **Traveller**, which avoids booking the same Trip twice for the same person.

I am having trouble finding and imagining the right associations needed for this project, especially with the Traveller model.
Here's what I've come up with for now:

**USER:**

has_one :cart

has_many :travellers (max 4)

has_many :trips, through: :travellers

**TRAVELLER:**

belongs_to :user

belongs_to :trip

**TRIP:**

has_many :travellers (max 8)

has_one_and_belongs_to_many :carts

**CART:**

belongs_to :user

has_one_and_belongs_to_many :trips

Does this sound right? I'm also having a hard time testing every association in the rails console.
Thank you for your help, and if you ever have tips on how to properly test these associations, and how to imagine them without getting confused, that would be great help!  (I've made some sketches on paper, but they only get me even more confused sometimes...)

Answer (score 1):

the association between trip and cart should be like

```
Trip
has_many :carts
<Validation for uniqueness>
Cart
has_many :trips
```

Comment: Would this still create a join table between the two?

Comment: no it won't create,
in that case it should be simply many to many relationship
and the uniqueness can be handled using validations